# Path variable not read correctly by OpenTextFileWriter

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with some code that gets the app location and stores in a folder some files. The issue is that the file writer is not reading the path correctly.

The path variable returns: `C:\Users\user\Desktop\RoboControl\bin\debug\scripts\`
But, the file writer has an exception not being able to find the path and attempts to write in here: `C:\scripts\test.txt`

I tried to work with more variables, a variable for the scripts directory and the variable of the file to be saved.

```vb
Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
Dim dpath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath()), "\scripts") ''scripts directory path, returns ok
Dim fpath = Path.Combine(dpath, TextBox1.Text) ''final file path, returns ok
file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(fpath, False) ''here the path variable is not read correctly
''Text from the first form (this form is a dialog box)
file.Write(Form1.TextBox1.Text)
file.Close()
```

Edit: one thing that I realised is that fpath does not contain the full dpath variable, just `\scripts\test.txt`, but the writer should create a file in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to get the folder path from `Application.ExecutablePath` because `Application.StartupPath` is that folder path.  You don't need to put slashes in your partial paths because `Path.Combine` does that for you.  You probably don't need to call `Path.Combine` multiple times because it has accepted multiple partial paths for some time now.  You can probably use this:

```
Dim filePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "scripts", TextBox1.Text)
```

See whether that gives you the correct path.  Note that there are no parentheses after `StartupPath` because it's a property, not a method.  Not sure whether that had any bearing on your issue.

Comment: Interestingly, in VB.NET it is actually perfectly valid to access a property with empty parentheses on the end. My guess is that this is because either case invokes the property getter (which _is_ a method that can take parameters). You can even declare a property with parentheses without having it turn into an array, if you put them after its name: `Public Property Value() As Integer` - this represents a single integer and can be accessed like: `Dim i As Integer = Me.Value` or: `Dim i As Integer = Me.Value()`. || Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5nAoh6

Comment: @VisualVincent I buy the parens for the getter but not in the declare. I think it is an error in the compiler.

Comment: @Mary : I don't think it is. In the declaration you can specify parameters which are used both for the getter and setter, i.e. `Public Property Value(ByVal Key As String) As Integer`, so empty parentheses represents a getter and setter with no parameters. Since properties are really just a combination of two methods VB.NET appears to treat them as such. You can use parantheses in any situation just like with a regular method. For instance `Test.Value() = 1056` (calling the setter with parentheses) is valid too.

Comment: @VisualVincent Thank you for the expanded explanation. I played with it a bit and this has opened up new ideas for Properties. It seems that if you do add a parameter to the declare, it must be present for both the getter and setter. As far as the empty parens, I will add to my very short list of what I like about C#. Different notation for method invocation ( ) and arrays [ ].

Comment: @Mary : _"It seems that if you do add a parameter to the declare, it must be present for both the getter and setter."_ - Yes of course, this is because the parameter is added to both the getter and the setter method. The `List(Of T).Item` property is an example of this: You cannot call it without specifying which index to get/set. The `Item` property is what's invoked when you do `List(x)` or `List(x) = y`.

Comment: @Mary : My bad, ignore the last thing I said. C# doesn't support parameterized properties, only indexed ones.

Comment: @VisualVincent I wonder if the VB parameterized properties are CIL compilant. Could C# use a VB class with parameterized properties? I would guess no. Well, cancel new ideas.